# WCF Restful and query string with special characters

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, query-string, wcf-rest

I am using WCF with Restful API.

From client, I make a GET request with query string "http://example.com/6500/%2fSIZ7".

With "6500" and "%2fSIZ7" are parameters.

But on server, I only receives value of "6500" and "SIZ17" and doesn't have special character "%2f".

I also try with another character, for example: "#"(encode before sending). It is working.

How do we send a query string with character "/"(%2f)?

Answer (score 0):

Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format. URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits. URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

Url encoded characters are listed at [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

From above list %2F is the encoded value of forward slash(/).

Comment: Yes, I replaced the special character to another symbol before encoding and it is working.